# I wrote a simple sequence. I use it for all tables

Tags: plsql, sequence

Why : Doesn't send the ID number one by one? Why do some tables start with e.g. 126 when these are the first entries? Do I have to make a separate sequence for each table?

CREATE SEQUENCE  "MMDS"."NEXT_ID"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 201 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL ;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geiCd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qN04.png)

Comment: Is it a problem that there is cache and no order ? I know it feels off, but for your application and data is will most probably not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

No problem in using either of these two options: you can have one sequence for all tables (simpler), or one sequence per table (more complicated, as you have to actually create it, manually).

Sequence makes sure that you'll get unique values, but they won't be consecutive. Your "issue" is related to caching. It is used for better performance, as Oracle "reserves" 20 values at a time. If you don't use all of them, they will be lost. But - never mind that, that's irrelevant in most cases. If you really need to have consecutive values, you'll have to develop your own solution (with a separate table, autonomous transaction function, worry about rollbacks and deleted values, ... not that simple).

---

Another option you might want to consider is using an **identity column** - if your database version supports it. Oracle will still use (and create, in the background) a sequence, but that option is simpler to use as you don't have to do *anything* - just declare column as such, e.g.

```
SQL> create table my_test
  2    (id    number   generated always as identity primary key);

Table created.

SQL> select sequence_name from user_sequences;

SEQUENCE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ISEQ$$_142849
```

---

**[EDIT]**, based on your comment

This is 18c and yes - it supports identity columns, but you have to use valid syntax.

```
SQL> select banner From v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> create table a1_sociala
  2    (id_measurement number generated by default as identity,
  3     name           varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into a1_sociala (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from a1_sociala;

ID_MEASUREMENT NAME
-------------- --------------------
             1 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, colleagues
I tried to change


alter table socialaaaa Modify id_measurement generated by default as identity (
Start with 1 increment by 1 cache 1)
ORA-30673: column to be modified is not an identity column
I am using Oracle Database 18c Express.
Can you confirm that this version supports or does not support generated by default as identity

Comment: Yes, it does. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: Can you tell me where I’m making a mistake?

~~~alter table socialaaaa Modify id_measurement generated by default as identity (
Start with 1 increment by 1 cache 1)~~~
ORA-30673: column to be modified is not an identity column 30673.0000 - “column to be modified is not an identity column” *Cause: An attempt was made to modify the identity properties of that is not an identity column. *Action: Modify the identity properties of an identity column.

Comment: ID_MEASUREMENT seems to be an "ordinary" column, it is **not** an identity column so you can't apply that ALTER TABLE statement to it. As far as I can tell, you can't do that. Instead, if you must, add a new IDENTITY column to existing table and drop the old ID column. Take care about existing values! Alternatively, instead of using IDENTITY column, create a sequence and a **trigger** which will both then act as if you have an IDENTITY column.